# Maven Build error while using pom version 3.0.1 on my Spring boot Java project on IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven pom version 3.0.1 and while building getting errors as below. I installed the certificate also in VDI of my java folder. Can you please help on this?

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.0.1

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0

Cannot resolve plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2

Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1
```

I java spring boot project with the pom version 3.0.1 and i installed the certificate also in VDI of my java folder. Still same issue on my IntelliJ IDE.

Could you please help on this?

Comment: IntelliJ IDE installed the same is sue in  java folder also in VDI certificate.

Comment: IDE installed in this folder >C:\Users\ARIMO\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JetBrains

and java in this folder for certificate ->C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.332.09-hotspot\jre\lib\security

Comment: Spring Boot 3.x needs `JDK 17`